# How to get required dataframe after pyspark pivot?

Tags: sql, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a spark dataframe:

```
+------+----------------+-------+------+---------+
|name  |           pDate| status|user  |userCount|
+------+----------------+-------+------+---------+
|janani|2022-03-04      |active |qwe123|1        |
|raj   |2022-03-03      |active |qwe123|1        |
|ram   |2022-03-01      |active |qwe123|1        |
|ram   |2022-03-02      |active |qwe123|1        |
+------+----------------+-------+------+---------+
```

when I pivoted the dataframe with the following code

```
pvtcountuser = countuser.groupby('pDate','name').pivot('pDate').max('userCount').fillna(0)
```

I get:

```
+----------------+------+----------+----------+----------+----------+
|pDate           |name  |2022-03-01|2022-03-02|2022-03-03|2022-03-04|
+----------------+------+----------+----------+----------+----------+
|2022-03-04      |janani|0         |0         |0         |1         |
|2022-03-03      |raj   |0         |0         |1         |0         |
|2022-03-01      |ram   |1         |0         |0         |0         |
|2022-03-02      |ram   |0         |1         |0         |0         |
+----------------+------+----------+----------+----------+----------+
```

but the required solution needed is:

```
+----------------+------+----------+----------+----------+----------+
|pDate           |name  |2022-03-01|2022-03-02|2022-03-03|2022-03-04|
+----------------+------+----------+----------+----------+----------+
|2022-03-04      |janani|0         |0         |0         |1         |
|2022-03-03      |raj   |0         |0         |1         |0         |
|2022-03-01      |ram   |1         |1         |0         |0         |
+----------------+------+----------+----------+----------+----------+
```

Please help on this

Comment: "DO NOT post images of code, data, error messages, etc." https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: This is a sample data, only given for understanding purpose.

Comment: It always is. Please revert back to the previous version.

Comment: Thank you!, I didn't see you had already edited it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

min(pDate) per name, could be achieved prior to the pivot, using windows function.
Once you have it, you can aggregate by both name and min_pDate.

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
from pyspark.sql.window import Window

sql_stmt = '''
select *
from   values    ('janani',date '2022-03-04','active','qwe123',1)
                ,('raj'   ,date '2022-03-03','active','qwe123',1)
                ,('ram'   ,date '2022-03-01','active','qwe123',1)
                ,('ram'   ,date '2022-03-02','active','qwe123',1) as t (name,pDate,status,user,userCount)
'''

countuser = spark.sql(sql_stmt)

pvtcountuser = (countuser
                .withColumn('min_pDate', F.min('pDate').over(Window.partitionBy('name')))
                .groupby('name', 'min_pDate')
                .pivot('pDate')
                .max('userCount')
                .fillna(0)
                .withColumnRenamed('min_pDate','pDate')
               )

pvtcountuser.show()
```

---

```
+------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+
|  name|     pDate|2022-03-01|2022-03-02|2022-03-03|2022-03-04|
+------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+
|janani|2022-03-04|         0|         0|         0|         1|
|   raj|2022-03-03|         0|         0|         1|         0|
|   ram|2022-03-01|         1|         1|         0|         0|
+------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+
```

Comment: I actually just realized that this is not exactly what you are looking for (I'm missing the pDate column)

Comment: See updated answer